# jQuery: get the HTML inside a certain tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this HTML page, and I want to create a jQuery method that gathers the HTML content of another page.

For instance, I want to get the HTML content between the  tags, including child tags, attributes, text..

I've come up with something like:

```
<script>
var page;
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
       type : "GET",
    url : "template.html",
    dataType : "html",
    success : function(html) {
    page = $(html).find('body').html();
            //do something

                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

but it doesn't do the trick.
any idea? thank you.

Comment: do you want to create another html file?

Comment: what do you mean "*it doesn't do the trick*" ? Does the ajax request completes successfully ? does the `html` variable get populated with what you expect ? .. what exactly goes wrong ?

Comment: @Hemant: I need to extract the html, process it and display it on the current page.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: the request is successful, but the page variable is empty.

Comment: use the `html` variable instead `$(html).find('body').html();` because `html` variable is the result of `ajax` call and `$(html).find('body').html();` is the html of current page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the JQuery Load-function.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

This function loads the html from the div with id `container` from the page `ajax/test.html` and puts the html into the div with id `result`.

source: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jQuery does not parse entire `html` pages as string..

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use the browser's **.innerHTML** property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as **`<html>`**, **`<title>`**, or **`<head>`** elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

So you need to bypass this limitation..

a work-around is to manually add the returned html to an html element.

```
success  : function(html){    
            var ndoc = document.createElement('html');
            ndoc.innerHTML = html;
            page = $('body', ndoc);
            console.log(page);
            }
```

Comment: hmm, I manage to extract the HTML this way, but not to display it using a .innerHTML javascript modify. Maybe it's because the page has already been rendered?

Comment: @Lorenzo, not sure what you mean.. the `page` variable will hold the `body` tag of the ajax result in memory as a jQuert object.. (*the console.log is for debugging and should be removed*)

Comment: I mean that if I try to call a javascript function passing the page variable, and in this function I try to inject the gathered HTML into the current HTML I don't have it shown, while if I use $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container'); I can see the actual HTML

Comment: i see... i ommited the last part of your convertion.. just add `.html()` at the end of my code to convert it to text.. `page = $('body', ndoc).html()`.